# Android Media Player (NvMM Client v0.1)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am hosting a jetty server on my AndroidPhone to which I connect the local media player via HTTP. This works great on most devices, but some older Motorola devices (and maybe others I am not yet aware of) cause problems:

when connecting they identify themselves as `User-Agent: NvMMClient/0.1 (Linux;Android 2.2.1)`.

I tried to set a content length to the HTTP response (usually I did chunked streaming). Using the content length this client connected 50+ times until after 10-20 seconds it starts playing. So the player CAN decode the media after all (its simple MP3). Using chunked streaming it connects twice and then gives up with `Error (1,0)`

any known issues / workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

turns out that Android Media Player version did not like chunked HTTP connections (real streaming). A HTTP response that specified the correct content length solved the issue.